# What is the size of an array after redefining its variable?

Tags: java, arrays, variables

In Java, I have an existing array of length N assigned to a variable called st. If I create a new array of the same type with size N + k called newSt. What is the result of newSt = st?
Will newSt have the contents of st and empty space or will newSt reduce its length to st's length?

```
Object[] st = new Object[20];

// st is filled

Object[] newSt = new Object[40];

newSt = st;
```

Comment: Did you try to check this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The length will be 20...

You can also test it yourself:

```
Object[] st = new Object[20];
System.out.println("st: " + st.length);
Object[] newSt = new Object[40];
newSt = st; // newSt was Object[40], st is Object[20] => newSt is now Object[20].
System.out.println("newSt: " + newSt.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused because you are trying to think this as a structural assignation, but it is a reference designation.

When you `secondArray = firstArray` you are making the variable `secondArray` to reference `firstArry`, both variables with different names reference the same object in memory. Your previous initialization of the `secondArray` is lost.

So the size of `newSt` and all the objects are the same as those for `st` because `newSt` is `st` but with another name.

What you are thinking would be something like a constructor that uses as argument another array and the size.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Variables names keep the reference of the actual array. So `st=new Object[20]` creates an array of size 20 and assigns the reference to `st` as well as `newSt=new Object[40]` creates an array of size 40 and assigns the reference to `newSt`.

So when we set `st=newSt`, we are just assigning refrence of the array to `st`  which is being referred by `newSt`. So now we can use `st` to access all the values of second array.

It won't do any kind of merge, Union or intersection of the arrays.